# For which $\alpha$ the function $f(x)=(1-2|x|/X)^\alpha$ is in the Sobolev space $W^{1,4}([-X/2,X/2])$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let the function f be: $$f(x)={\left(1-\frac{2|x|}{X}\right)}^{\alpha}, $$ 
$X$ is just a real parameter.

How can I find the set of $\alpha$ such that $f \in W^{1,4}([-\frac{X}{2},\frac{X}{2}])$ ?
I know the definition but I'm new with this kind of question so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the definition is enough, here: the constraining condition is that the derivative of $f$ be in $L^4$, i.e. $x^{\alpha-1}\in L^4(0,1)$ or $4(\alpha-1)>-1$